# How to integrate a payment gateway in my mobile website?

Tags: mobile, mobile-phones, payment-gateway, mobile-website

I have a scenario for which I am searching a solution.

I already have a website that is accessible via desktop browsers, and I will be porting my website to make it compatible with Mobile Phone browsers.
I'll be redirecting all the traffic coming to my server via a mobile phone browser, to my mobile site, and will also be having a dedicated domain for it.

However, My website is having some functions which require the users to pay, and for that I have integrated payment gateways in my desktop website. (Say PayPal)

Now I need the same functionality to be available in my mobile site too.
What will be the differences and the things that I am required to do?
Is it totally different than what we do while integrating Payment Gateway with our Desktop Website?

Please suggest and if possible, point me towards some nice articles.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just talked to PayPal people, and they have a way for called 'Mobile Checkout'
I'll use that.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create the payment fields you need in your mobile site and ten connect those fields to the gateway using their API or web services. gotoBilling.com can provide you the gateway and various [development tools](http://www.gotobilling.com/Corporate/index.php/developers.html) to make your mobile site functional.

Steve

Steve Roderick

steve@gotobilling.com

Comment: That would be the ultimate thing I'll have to try out, then I can also implement things like PayPal API at my server. But I was wanting to have something like a payment gateway which lets me post a bundle of data to it, handle the credit card thing, and gives me a bundle of data back after transaction.